# Is it okay Grails jobs reuses a Hibernate session per thread?

Tags: hibernate, grails

I noticed a single Hibernate session is being reused between executions of my Quartz job (one session per thread surely). That leads to such bugs like "object was update in a different transaction" (yes it was!) Also such behaviour break the basic [session-per-request](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/SessionsAndTransactions#The_scope_of_a_unit_of_work) pattern. I couldn't tell how long one such session actually lives - may be forever?..

1) Maybe such re-usage of session is still correct?

2) How should I tweak some setting to force open new session for each job execution? Without manually calling `withNewSession()`...

Example:

```
class PersistentCat {
    UUID unique
    static transients = ['unique']
}

class MyJob {
    def execute() {
        def ssn = sessionFactory.currentSession
        def tid = Thread.currentThread().id
        def pfx = "thr:$tid, ssn:${ssn.hashCode()}"
        def cat = PersistentCat.get(2265734)
        if ( ! cat.unique) {
            cat.unique = UUID.randomUUID()
            println "$pfx - assigning ${cat.unique} to${cat.hashCode()}"
        } else {
            println "$pfx - having ${cat.unique} already for ${cat.hashCode()}"
        }
    }
}
```

(In real life I do call a transactioned service in my job but the things stays the same.)

Below it the output (each line denotes single job execution). Note the first and the last job executions: the same session `741211827` is shared between executions and we have the same unique persistent object `***-7221e7a97f3d` attached to that session.

```
thr:40, ssn:741211827 - assigning ***-7221e7a97f3d to 1067276977
thr:41, ssn:1711904876 - assigning ***-f60b9b9b8ae2 to 1905091715
thr:42, ssn:1793712482 - assigning ***-7d2a89712099 to 187890840
thr:43, ssn:1974717027 - assigning ***-aff9889f9147 to 1433286500
thr:44, ssn:873758823 - assigning ***-6fd87ccfbff5 to 1676979558
thr:45, ssn:1049618761 - assigning ***-d9f15c7429ec to 892993015
thr:46, ssn:1827346548 - assigning ***-9c92f4fea54f to 89176513
thr:47, ssn:212156716 - assigning ***-c5acc08ba7cc to 2016599572
thr:40, ssn:741211827 - having ***-7221e7a97f3d already for 1067276977
```

Grails 2.2.0, Quartz plugin 1.0-RC2

Comment: Why is the last thread same as the first one (40)? Should not it be a new thread as others till 47 continuing to 48? Somewhere you are getting hold of the first thread again???

Comment: Moreover I would try shifting this piece of code (present inside `execute()`) to a transactional grails service and see how it behaves. Shouldn't the service class create a new session every time for different threads?

Comment: **dmahapatro**, there is a thread pool so threads are being reused. I tried moving the code into a service: that does not change the things and it should not, I believe - some session pre-exists already, so there is no reason to create a new one.

Comment: I am not sure whether the session gets closed from a Quartz job artefact. Can you manually try closing the session at the end by using `SessionFactoryUtils.closeSession(ssn)` or `ssn.close()`?

Comment: If I manually close that pre-existent session, next time I get the following exception calling any transactional service --"CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open Hibernate Session for transaction; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException"